# Run multiple configuration with one click - JetBrains IDEs

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm setting up a new dev environment on PhpStorm, and like always, I have 2 config to run my app : 1 config to run the frontend and 1 config to run the backend. I'd like to know if it is possible to run these configs with only one click (one run or one config that open a terminal for each config).

I tried to add one of the config in the "Before launch", but as it is not a "one shot" command, it does not start the next one. I would need to launch it in a new console.

Comment: IntelliJ has a launch type called "Compound" which can be used to launch multiple other launch configurations at the same time (even different times). Since PhpStorm is based on the same stack, I suspect that exists too. Press the "+" at the top left corner of the Edit Run Configuration window.